# Sporadic DNS issues, ubuntuMate 16.04 LTS

Tags: dns

in the past month or so I've started experiencing extremely frustrating DNS issues, whereby I often see a 'connecting message in the browser for 10 -30 seconds before a site loads, and also often have connection timeouts.

After much googling I tried this suggestions
Remove (or comment out) the below line from /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf: dns=dnsmasq

It is definitely something related to my Ubuntu install because another PC running windows on the same network has zero issues.
but it has made no difference.
Can anyone offer me either a solution or some good troubleshooting steps?

Answer (score 1):

I'm on 14.04 LTS but had the same issue and it turned out that my dns-searches was somehow looking at the wrong place (locally).

In the NetworkManager (`nm-connection-editor`) my DNS server was set to `192.168.100.1`. But when checking `/etc/resolv.conf` is tells me `127.0.1.1`. So if I try to lookup something:

```
$ nslookup www.google.com
Server:        127.0.1.1
...
```

After removing the `dns=dnsmas`-row from `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and rebooting it works flawlessly. `/etc/resolv.conf` tells me `192.168.100.1` and first line of `nslookup`:

```
$ nslookup www.google.com
Server:        192.168.100.1
...
```